# Mongoose, Node JS, MongoDB and or query not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm running MongoDB version v3.6.8, Node v8.12.0 & Mongoose v5.4.4.

This purely OR query produces results:

```
db.messages.find( { $or : [ { senderId : "5c97ca3eed0cc17e8cfb0486" }, { receiverId : "5c8430effe7df210ee3264bf" } ] })
```

This AND OR query doesn't return any results:

```
db.messages.find( { $and : [ { $or : [ { senderId : "5c8430effe7df210ee3264bf" }, { receiverId : "5c97ca3eed0cc17e8cfb0486" } ] }, { $or : [ { senderId : "5c97ca3eed0cc17e8cfb0486" }, { receiverId : "5c8430effe7df210ee3264bf" } ] } ] } )
```

Although since it's an AND OR query if should return results because one OR query did. Am I missing something here? Is there a fault in my AND OR query? I went straight from the Mongo docs here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

For the AND operator in your query to be true, both OR expressions must be true.
the first expression is probably returning false.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who runs into the same problem in the future I mixed the $and & $or around so the correct query would be:

```
db.messages.find( { $or : [ { $and : [ { senderId : "5c8430effe7df210ee3264bf" }, { receiverId : "5c97ca3eed0cc17e8cfb0486" } ] }, { $and : [ { senderId : "5c97ca3eed0cc17e8cfb0486" }, { receiverId : "5c8430effe7df210ee3264bf" } ] } ] } )
```